# Knob.js as a progressbar for Soundmanager2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, soundmanager2, jquery-knob

I am trying to use Knob.js (http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/) as a progress bar. I have found code for soundmanager2

```
$(".progBar").css('width', ((this.position/this.duration) * 100) + '%');
```

That works for a normal div width progress bar, but obviously with Knob, we must alter the value of the input.

I have seen those following code for updating the input value, but am unable to get it to properly work.

```
$(function() {
 $(".dial").knob({
  'draw' : function () { 
    $(this.i).val(this.cv + '%')
  }
 })
})
```

Some context of where my code is coming from... it is a music site where there are multiple songs, each with its own Knob circle. Each knob input has a unique ID of knob-###, or the variable 'knob_ID'

Here my entire code:

```
play: function(){ 
   var track_id = this.get('id');
   var knobID = $("#knob-" + track_id);
   var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
      id: track_id,
      url: 'mp3/path.mp3',
      autoplay: false,
      whileplaying: function() {
         var percentage = $((this.position/this.duration) * 100);
            $('#positionBar').css('width', ((this.position/this.duration) * 100) + '%'); 
            console.log(percentage);
            knobID.knob({
              'draw' : function () {
                 $(this.i).val(percentage + '%')
               }
            });
         },
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you create a failing bin. emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: Here is a jsbin example. http://jsbin.com/seposebu/6/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a rough demo](http://jsbin.com/seposebu/7/edit) of updating the knob plugin as sound manager plays a file. You may need to do some more customization to make it a fully reusable and configurable component.

SoundKnob2 view

```
App.SoundKnob2 = Em.View.extend({
  knobInput: null,
  sound: null,
  playState: false,
  playStateLabel: function() {
    return this.get('playState')? 'PAUSE' : 'PLAY';
  }.property('playState'),

  initSound: function() {
    soundManager.setup({
  preferFlash: true,
      url: '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/soundmanager2/2.97a.20131201/cors/',
      onready: function() {
        var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
          autoLoad: true,
          autoPlay: false,
          id: 'aSound',
          url: 'http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/rain.mp3'
        });

        this.set('sound', mySound);
      }.bind(this),
      ontimeout: function() {
        console.log('timeout');
      }
    });
  }.on('init'),

  didInsertElement: function() {
    var knobInput = this.$().find('input');
    knobInput.knob({displayInput: false});
    this.set('knobInput', knobInput);
    //knobInput.val(50).trigger('change');
  },

  actions: {
    toggle: function() {
      this.toggleProperty('playState');
      var knob = this.get('knobInput');

      if(this.get('playState')) { 
        this.get('sound').play({
          onfinish: function() {
            knob.val(0).trigger('change');
            this.toggleProperty('playState');
          }.bind(this),
          whileplaying: function() {
            console.log(this.position);
            var pos = (this.position/ this.duration) * 100;
            knob.val(pos).trigger('change');
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.get('sound').pause();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

It can be used in a template like

```
{{#view App.SoundKnob2 class="sound-knob2"}}
    <input />
    <button {{action 'toggle' target="view"}}>{{view.playStateLabel}}</button>
{{/view}}
```

Comment: That worked, but I have a follow-up question that I would really appreciate if you could help me out. If I have multiple views, each with an ID attached to the Button, how can I remove PLAY property of all other views on toggle of this button. Second question is how can I display an image in place of the Play/Pause button (ie Play/Pause icons), and lastly, how can I attach the ID of each button to the url of the mp3 file? Here is a quick jsbin: http://jsbin.com/seposebu/8/edit

Comment: @jeanhules I've updated the bin. It should answer most of ur questions. http://jsbin.com/seposebu/10/edit